# jQuery simplemodal disable scrolling

Tags: jquery, scroll, simplemodal

I have more than 2000 pixels scrolling content on a page.

If the user clicks a `div` a scrolling content pops up in a simplemodal window. Now my client wants to make the original page non-scrollable while the modal window is up. (Of course the modal should be still scrollable.)

Is it even possible?

Edit: I have tried your suggestions. Basically it works, but the problem is a little bit complicated:

```
$(".foReadMoreLink a").click(function(){
    if ($('#modalBox').length == 0)
    $('body').append('<div style="display:none" id="modalBox"></div>')
    $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    $.post('jquery/loadarticle.php',{id:$(this).attr('id')},function(data){
        $('#modalBox').html(data).modal({overlayClose:'true'});
    })
    return false;
});
```

I use return false on the links so bots and users without JavaScript (yes, that's 2%) can open the articles. With the code above it works as expected, but after closing the modal I have to have back the scrollbar but this code won't work:

```
$(".foReadMoreLink a").click(function(){
    if ($('#modalBox').length == 0)
    $('body').append('<div style="display:none" id="modalBox"></div>')
    $('body').css({'overflow':'hidden'});
    $.post('jquery/loadarticle.php',{id:$(this).attr('id')},function(data){
        $('#modalBox').html(data).modal({onClose:function(){$('body').css({'overflow':'auto'})},overlayClose:'true'});
    })
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 22):

In your script to open your modal:

```
$("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
```

And on close:

```
$("html,body").css("overflow","auto");
```

(HTML and body are required as the scroll bars are attached to different parts of the browser depending on which you are using)

Comment: well thats actually the same what I said in my answer ;)

Answer (score 18):

Turning the scrollbars on and off will cause the content to shift and the overlay will no longer cover the whole window.  Here's how to fix it.

```
var oldBodyMarginRight = $("body").css("margin-right");
$.modal(iframe, {
    onShow: function () {
        // Turn off scroll bars to prevent the scroll wheel from affecting the main page.  Make sure turning off the scrollbars doesn't shift the position of the content.
        // This solution works Chrome 12, Firefox 4, IE 7/8/9, and Safari 5.
        // It turns off the scroll bars, but doesn't prevent the scrolling, in Opera 11 and Safari 5.
        var body = $("body");
        var html = $("html");
        var oldBodyOuterWidth = body.outerWidth(true);
        var oldScrollTop = html.scrollTop();
        var newBodyOuterWidth;
        $("html").css("overflow-y", "hidden");
        newBodyOuterWidth = $("body").outerWidth(true);
        body.css("margin-right", (newBodyOuterWidth - oldBodyOuterWidth + parseInt(oldBodyMarginRight)) + "px");
        html.scrollTop(oldScrollTop); // necessary for Firefox
        $("#simplemodal-overlay").css("width", newBodyOuterWidth + "px")
    },
    onClose: function () {
        var html = $("html");
        var oldScrollTop = html.scrollTop(); // necessary for Firefox.
        html.css("overflow-y", "").scrollTop(oldScrollTop);
        $("body").css("margin-right", oldBodyMarginRight);
        $.modal.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: Still able to scroll in Chrome unfortunately, thanks for the setup tho :)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
overflow:hidden
```

Apply it to the page when modal dialog is opened and remove it when the dialog is destroyed. This will hide your scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

I found `overflow:hidden` not so nice since it hides the content behind the semi-transparant overlay if the page is scrolled halfway.

I came up with the following, rather elaborate solution. It disables scrolling in all possible detectable ways I found. And puts the scrollposition straight back to the old position if the page was still scrolled somehow.

```
var popupOpened = false;

function openPopup()
{
    popupOpened = true;

    //catch middle mouse click scrolling
    $(document).bind('mousedown',disableMiddleMouseButtonScrolling);

    //catch other kinds of scrolling
    $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel',disableNormalScroll);

    //catch any other kind of scroll (though the event wont be canceled, the scrolling will be undone)
    //IE8 needs this to be 'window'!
    $(window).bind('scroll',disableNormalScroll);

    $("#layover").css({"opacity" : "0.7"}).fadeIn();
    $("#popup").fadeIn(300,function()
    {
        //use document here for crossbrowser scrolltop!
        oldScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    });
}

function closePopup()
{
    popupOpened = false;
    $("#layover").fadeOut();
    $("#popup").fadeOut(300,function(){
        $(document).unbind('mousedown',disableMiddleMouseButtonScrolling);
        $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll wheel',disableNormalScroll);
        $(window).unbind('scroll',disableNormalScroll);
    });
}

function disableMiddleMouseButtonScrolling(e)
{
    if(e.which == 2)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
}

function disableNormalScroll(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').scrollTop(oldScrollTop);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This option works like a charm:

```
document.documentElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case in tag `<a>` param `href = "#"`.
So solution be:

```
href="javascript:void(0);"
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow... but this answer isn't a solution to the question that was asked.