# CSS solution to only scroll current div with the mousewheel - not the div behind it.

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Consider the following:

[image: Scrolling Div's]

Consider the scenario where I have my mouse positioned in **div A** and I use the mouse wheel to scroll to the bottom or top of **divA**.  When I reach the bottom of **div A** and keep scrolling with the wheel, it will begin to scroll **div B**.  I would like the mouse wheel to only scroll the current div that the cursor is sitting on.

Is this possible with any standard CSS?  Or do I need to wire up JS/jQuery events to detect the div I am currently on and stop the scroll event?  I am hoping there is a CSS solution to this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: IIRC, most browsers do this by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem possible.  I will gladly accept another answer if someone posts one!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is what you need:

[How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/programmatically-disable-scrolling)

Basically on mouseover you'll disable scrolling for the rest of the page by setting overflow to hidden. And then undo it on mouseout.

Edit: Make sure to handle the case of mouseout, alt+tab then mousemove. You may have to tweak it to make sure they dont get locked out of scrolling with the mouse out of the box.

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for trying to read first thing in the morning, sorry. Though thinking on it, any CSS solution that uses expressions I would avoid for performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need this, NO CSS solution:

```
<script>
$("#div-A").bind("mousewheel", function(e){
var intElemScrollHeight = document.getElementById("div-A").scrollHeight;
var intElemClientHeight = document.getElementById("div-A").clientHeight;
if( intElemScrollHeight - $("#div-A").scrollTop() === intElemClientHeight) {
    $(document).bind("mousewheel", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0 ) {
    if($("#div-A").scrollTop() != 0) {
        $(document).unbind("mousewheel"); 
    } else {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}});
$("#div-A").on("mouseleave", function(event) {
   $(document).unbind("mousewheel");
});
</script>
```