# jQuery - iPad/iPhone - enable scrolling after disabling it

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, scroll, dom-events

I have disabled scrolling on the iPad using:

```
function disableScrolling() {
    document.ontouchmove = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to simply enable it again?

It would be especially helpful in a function like:

```
function enableScrolling() {
    // enable scrolling
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should work,

```
var disableScroll = false;

function disableScrolling() {
    disableScroll = true;
}


function enableScrolling() {
    disableScroll = false;
}

document.ontouchmove = function(e){
   if(disableScroll){
     e.preventDefault();
   } 
}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly! I combined it with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3656618/1359306) answer to disable/enable on both touch devices and desktop browsers.

Comment: This is perfect! Nice and clean. Thank you.