# Changing Height and width of modal dynamically when browser screen resolution changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, simplemodal

I was working on a jquery simple modal.  I am trying to load it- on-load and after some 15 Sec it will close automatically.  So what i cannot achieve is if i am setting a width and height to that modal and if the users browser screen resolution changes([`ctrl(+)`]or[`ctrl(-)`]) the size of the modal will varies.  So i tried to catch the user's screen resolution using `screen.width` and `screen.height` and assigning that width to that modal.  But it is messing up i don't know why.  [Here is the demo link](http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/test/sample_modal/) of what i am trying to do.  This is my jquery code i am using.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function () {
    var width = screen.width,
        height = screen.height;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (screen.width !== width || screen.height !== height) {
            width = screen.width;
            height = screen.height;
            $(window).trigger('resolutionchange');
        }
    }, 50);
}());
$.modal($("#basic-modal-content"));
$("#simplemodal-container").width(screen.width);
$("#simplemodal-container").height(screen.height);  
});
setTimeout(function() { 
$.modal.close();
}, 15000);

</script>
```

The actual thing is i am trying to hide my screen and put an ad in the modal until the page loads.  Hope my question is clear.  Thank you in Advance !!

Comment: You want to dynamically change the `width` and `height` of the modal when the window is zoomed in and out?

Comment: Obviously you are right.

Comment: Have you tried capturing the event when the window is resized? Like `$(window).resize(function(){
    //Scale the width and height of modal
  });`

Comment: No.  I am just capturing the screen width and height.

Comment: The `screen` `width` is different from the `window` `width`. Screen width is taken from the monitors resolution.

Comment: Okay let me try with your suggestions.

Comment: window.width is not working @dunli.

Comment: Can you setup a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? So that it would be easy for me to help you.

Comment: http://vignesh.gvignesh.org/test/sample_modal/
This is a model of modal.  just take a look.

Comment: can download the content there and test it in your environment itself.  I dont know how to setup a simplemodal in fiddle.

Comment: I'm on it. It'll take time maybe.

Comment: Okay.  I am just waiting.  mean time i am also trying.

Comment: You would like your modal to take the whole screen of the browser?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to hide the original screen meanwhile loading this modal until original content loads completely.

Comment: Hi, I'm in the resizing part yet. You may want to start from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DqBKQ/6/).

Comment: in JsFiddle itis working fine.  at the same time when i copy same code and try it in my system, it fails.

Comment: Can you post the link to your working copy in your system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have here an update in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DqBKQ/7/).

I have added this:

```
modal.css({
  width: w + ($(window).width() - w),
  height: h + ($(window).height() - h)
});
```

to your script. The good thing is that the `modal` is occupying the whole screen, on the other hand when the window is resized the border (green) will be gone, only the contents of the modal are shown.

But it will be a good start for you.

UPDATE:

I've updated the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DqBKQ/10/).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey really woking super in fiddle.  Lot of thanks for you help.

Comment: One more dunil.  Can we disable browsers scroll bar when this modal loads?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/programmatically-disable-scrolling) might help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function() {
        (function () {
        var width = screen.width,
            height = screen.height;
        setInterval(function () {
            if (screen.width !== width || screen.height !== height) {
                width = screen.width;
                height = screen.height;
                $(window).trigger('resolutionchange', width, height);
            }
        }, 50);
    }());
    $.modal($("#basic-modal-content"));
    $("#simplemodal-container").width(screen.width);
    $("#simplemodal-container").height(screen.height);  
    });

    $(window).on('resolutionchange', function(width, height){
        $("#simplemodal-container").width(width);
        $("#simplemodal-container").height(height); 

       //you also need to set position left:0 and top:0;
    });

    setTimeout(function() { 
    $.modal.close();
    }, 15000);

</script>
```

but i suggestion to use this way, because you want fill browser window

```
#simplemodal-container {
   left:0;
   top:0;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   position:fixed;
} 

<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#simplemodal-container').fadeOut();
    },1500);
</script>
```

or in other way [your solution]:

```
<script>

    $(function() {

       var width = screen.width,
            height = screen.height;

       $.modal($("#basic-modal-content"));
       $("#simplemodal-container").width(width).height(height).css({top:0,left:0});

       $(window).resize(function(){
            width = screen.width;
                height = screen.height;
                $(window).trigger('resolutionchange', width, height);
       });


       $(window).on('resolutionchange', function(width, height){
          $("#simplemodal-container").width(width).height(height).css({top:0,left:0});
          //if you have padding for modal, remove it
       });

       setTimeout(function() { 
          $.modal.close();
       }, 15000);

    });

</script>
```