# disable scroll with overlay active like Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, scroll

I was wondering how does Facebook handles the browser scroll when one opens an image for a larger view. It seems the scroll gets disabled but remains visible (the element container). I want to create a similar behaviour on a website, so that when I call the overlay to display the image the scroll gets "disabled" to avoid people from scrolling and loosing sight of the overlay.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is simply set

```
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
```

whilst you don't want the user to be able to scroll, then revert to

```
document.body.style.overflow = '';
```

when you do.

[**Here is a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/n82VV/1/) (clicking it switches between the two states)

Comment: I was actually interested in knowing how to make the rectangular scroll handler disapear and mantain the container and arrows, like Facebook does.

Comment: Try to open one image in facebook, and you'll see that not only the scroll stops as there are some scroll elements that dissapear, as if there was no need to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer, working exactly like facebook's scroll. The answer originally was posted by 'Patrick DaVader' and I think it's worth sharing it:

> To turn OFF scrolling try this:
>
> ```
> var current = $(window).scrollTop();
>
> $(window).scroll(function() {
>     $(window).scrollTop(current);
> });
> ```
>
> to reset:
>
> ```
> $(window).off('scroll');
> ```

Link where I found it: [How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery/29564098#29564098)