# Jquery facebook like slide panel scroll issues

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

Hey all i am using code from [HERE](http://takien.github.io/jPushMenu/)

It works good BUT once the menu is slid out and i scroll all the way down to the bottom-and keep scrolling it actually starts to scroll the main page.

I have set up a preview in jsfiddle of this to better grasp what i am talking about.

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/WeDbS/)

I have already tried:

```
$(".container").attr('disabled',true);
```

But that does not seem to disable it from scrolling...

I found some [jquery code that disables scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery) for the whole page but that wont work since i need to be able to scroll in the menu panel.

I am using this for a mobile app using Phonegap and Jquery Mobile. And yes, i do know that Jquery mobile has a "slide panel" but it doesn't work well.

What would i be missing?