# disable scrolling but retain scrolling animation when using anchors in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a one-page layout with a navigation menu using #´s to navigate. I want to disable scolling via mousewheel / touchpad / keyboard completely so the user needs to use the menu. Using the menu for navigation, scrolling animation should be used. To create the scrolling animation i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var target = this.hash,
    $target = $(target);

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
    }, 600, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
    });
});
});
```

I tried methods from [How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery), but either they kill the animation (when putting noScroll on the body) or the animation behaves strangely, scrolling into the wrong direction and then jumping to the destination page, i.e. when using

```
$('html, body').css({
'overflow': 'hidden',
'height': '100%'
})
```

I also tried mixing these codes to disable scrolling and renable it on click, then again disable it, which didn´t work for me, then again I don´t know much about javascript / jquery. Can somebody offer a working solution?