# disable main window scrolling - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webpage with a lightbox in it, inside the lightbox there is a scrollbar.
I want to disable the main window scrollbar and keep the lightbox scrollbar enabled.

Not just to hide the scrollbar but to disable scrolling of the window at all (beside scrolling the lightbox).

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call

```
$("body").scroll(function(e){ e.preventDefault()});
```

when lightbox is opened.

You also may be interested [with this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817899/jquery-or-javascript-how-to-disable-window-scroll-without-overflowhidden)

Comment: this just hides the scrollbars, but i can still scroll with the mouse

Comment: using this code the page still can be scrolled... any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look at the link in the answer, you can find few suggestions there.

Comment: Thanks found the answer in the link

Comment: For me it doesn't work but I use this code and it works: $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            });

Answer (score 4):

You dont need jQuery. Use Stylesheet:

```
 html, body {
      overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: this just hides the scrollbars, but i can still scroll with the mouse

Comment: You also need to add `overflow:hidden;` to any child elements you may have.