# Preventing downward scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am looking to try and prevent downward scroll whilst allowing upward scroll is this possible using either css or javascript/jQuery?

Comment: How will you go up without going down? I can't understand the question. Can you show an example?

Comment: basically I am using css transitions and going between pages. I am going for something similar to parallax and when the user is on the page at the bottom they obviously can't go down. Each 'page' is a scene in the software I am using see this link for more info: http://1drv.ms/1M4vlIj

Comment: Tried using this? http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Don't break expected behaviors.  Your users will think your page/site is broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use stopPropogation and preventDefault, as seen here > [jQuery or Javascript - how to disable window scroll without overflow:hidden;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19817899/jquery-or-javascript-how-to-disable-window-scroll-without-overflowhidden)

stopPropogation stops the event from bubbling to parents and preventDefault attempts to cancel the event if possible.

So I would bind these to a scroll handler.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropogation();
});
```