# Stop page scrolling on ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How do i prevent my page to stop scroll to up on an ajax call,

I am using a universal overlay div on ajax start and end like,

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("body").on({
        ajaxStart: function() { 
            $(this).addClass("loading");
        },
        ajaxStop: function() { 
            $(this).removeClass("loading");
        }
    });
    //return false // if i use this line, overlay div no more appears
});
```

Immediately after an ajax call, overlay div appears and page scrolls up.

I am calling it on these evens, 'onclick' 'onblur' 'onchange'

like,

```
<input type="text" onblur="callAjax(); return false" />
```

Comment: `As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.` The same of course for `ajaxStop()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)