# How to disable scrolling of a page when mouse is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2.3

I have a component that is draggable on the page but I dont want the component to be dragged out of the current visible of the web-page, as we all know that when we click a component and hold the click and then drag it to the end or top of page while still holding the click the page starts scrolling, so how do i make sure that when mouse is clicked then page does not scroll so that i dont allow dragging of the component to an area that is not visible in the present visibility of the web-page.

I hope I was able to explain this in a proper way..

Comment: You can't disable scrolling but you could try reversing any scrolling as done here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3656618/2443946

Comment: What about placing a container it is confined to and setting overflow to none.. lemme see if i can find my old script..

Comment: hrm.. jquery has a method that handles scroll functionality for dragging it looks like. check into their source code and find out how if you don't want to use jQuery?