# How to stop scrolling of page when open popup

Tags: jquery

I am working on jquery popup.

When popup is opened i need to scroll the content into it.

But it is showing problem when i am trying to scroll the content with mouse wheel. It **scrolls the background page also**. I have used:

```
 $(window).scroll(function() { return false; });
```

but it stops the scrolling of popup content also and with

```
 $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
```

it hides the scroll from background page. Is there any another way **to prevent the background page to scroll**?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery

Comment: But i am not getting any solution from this.

Comment: I think i missing something but you tried to make the html and the body with 100% height and overflow hidden? I'm confuse with this sentence: "When popup is opened i need to scroll the content into it." If the above didn't help you, could you explain that a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
$('body').css("height",$( window ).height());
$('body').css("overflow","hidden");
```

Comment: Thats the same link provided in the first comment

Comment: Yes but you i have given direct link for that comment which you use

Comment: Yes, I have got a solution from this link. Thanks a lot. I have used this plugin. $.disablescroll

Comment: @Nimesh07 my bad! anyway, I don't know how it's possible that the OP "not getting any solution from this" but finally thats the acepted answer.

Comment: I have modified that code. please check it may be help to you

Answer (score 0):

I found this.Prevent Page behind JQuery UI Dialog from Scrolling. Not tested.
http://coding.abel.nu/2013/02/prevent-page-behind-jquery-ui-dialog-from-scrolling/

Comment: Please include content from the link itself in case the link goes down