# How do I use disable scrolling on click in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, scroll

Trying to disable scrolling if the user clicks a button.
I have tried:

```
$(window).bind('scroll');
```

Inside a click function, but that doesn't work. Could someone help me?
I have looked around and couldn't find a straight answer or a working solution.

Comment: What is initializing the scrolling? Depending on the element, you could use ```$(element).click(function(event){ event.preventDefault(); });```

Comment: When users click on buttons it shouldn't scroll at all. I am missing information..

Comment: Is it scrolling or page jumping you want to prevent???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use CSS:

```
body{overflow:hidden;}
```

### jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("body").css("overflow","hidden");
});
```

Comment: @BojanPetkovski It disables scrolling. I'd make a fiddle, but it won't be functional through the jsfiddle app.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $(".div").css({
    'overflow' : 'hidden',
     'height' : '100%'
 });
});
```

This answer is reference from [How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)

Answer (score -1):

The following JSFiddle snippet also disables scrolling through the Arrow Keys or PageUp/Down Keys:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jsfrocha/DHz77/194/)

Mainly the method:

```
(...)

function disable_scroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', wheel, false);
  }
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = wheel;
  document.onkeydown = keydown;
}

(...)
```

Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily).

Comment: This is not jQuery as the op has requested.