# How do I disable window scroll in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I've downloaded a wonderful template and I made some changes to it.

The problem is when I click on some links it automatically scrolls up.

How can I prevent it from scrolling up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to programmatically disable page scrolling with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)

Comment: have you added links

Comment: @RiccardoDegan that post does not cover anything about scroll on click.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason why a page would scroll up on a click of a link is because of the anchors... Please check your links' `href`, and make sure they do not contain a `#` . Usually, downloadable templates use placeholder links and put just the `#` inside the `href` so it acts like a link but points to the top of the page.

Comment: It is a correct investigation but incomplete answer. The [full answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29004028/295783) is given by Roko

Comment: @mplungjan IMO, preventing the defaults on a click of a #'d anchor is a band aid solution. Removing the # is the only real solution...

Comment: I am not a purist. The "#" has been used by millions to denote a placeholder for links that execute script so it does not give error when clicked and to get a pointer for free. I am by the way not convinced that removing the # will make a difference since the link will then likely load "/" instead but I have not tested that

Answer (score 1):

You can *event.preventDefault* on every anchor that has *hash* `#` as *href*:

```
// Remove after testing
$("[href='#']").click(function( e ){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```