# Cant stop page scroll with e.preventDefault();

Tags: jquery

I want to completely disable scrolling on the page with jquery (NOT body overflow:hidden).

I thought this would work but for some reason it doesn't.

```
$( window ).on( "scroll", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xatidu/4/edit?html,css,output

Comment: did you used datatables , because i had same issue

Answer (score 4):

I tried doing the same thing a month ago and managed to get it working like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery)