# JS prevent scrollTo from called from external js

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to prevent `window.scrollTo`, we have a problem with an external library injecting an UI component and then it will scroll to the top of the page, which is terrible for user experience, because you will scroll into this component and page will jump to top of window.

appreciate any great suggestions.

Comment: What is being injected?

Comment: the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery may help you, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question

> Is there a way to prevent window.scrollTo

Yes, you can store it in a variable, and override it:

```
window._scrollTo = window.scrollTo;
window.scrollTo = function() { };
```

Then, if you need to use `scrollTo` yourself, you can simply use the moved function:

```
window._scrollTo(...);
```

However, it does not sound correct.
You need to find the reason of this problem, and fix it.