# Keep horizontal scrollbars but disable horizontal wheel scroll when hover insise div aera and work again when hover on horizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript

I have some horizontal div inside long verical aera I want keep big vertical div scroll working inside body with mouse wheel (lift icon), I want also keep all my horizontal scrollbar: travelator icons But Disabled horizontal mouse wheel only of all my horizontal DIV's when mouse is hover in horizontal DIV area only AND work again when hover is exactly on the horizontal scrollbar

I didn't find javascript code that work

[image]

Comment: you can do this with css. Add overflow-x: hidden; Also javascript is not the same as java :)

Comment: Please show what efforts have you taken to solve your problem. Include coding to show your own work.

Comment: Its new to me that you can scroll horizontally when theres the possibility to scroll vertically also. Is there a mouse that can do that??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3656592/how-to-programmatically-disable-page-scrolling-with-jquery here you can find a piece of code, that fixes the position by resetting it to state previous of the scroll action, maybe you can fix it up to just enable it for the intended direction

Comment: this one no work propbably because there is anoher div inside the container: $('#container').hover(function() { $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){ stopWheel(); }); }, function() { $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll'); }); function stopWheel(e){ if(!e){ /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari / e = window.event; } if(e.preventDefault) { / Chrome, Safari, Firefox / e.preventDefault(); } e.returnValue = false; / IE7, IE8 */ }

Comment: I think this javascript I use no permit disable http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

Answer (score 1):

You may do it with javascript, but theese are simple operations with css via JS:

```
[your element].style.overflowY = "scroll";
[your element].style.overflowX = "hidden";
```

That should work)

Comment: Thank you a lot Dzi.  ...I want keep show all my 10 horizontal scrollbars; only disable mouse wheel and only disable when it's is on text area, no disable when hover on horizontal scrollbar

Comment: This code no work : $('#container').hover(function() {
    $(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll',function(){ 
        stopWheel(); 
    });
}, function() {
    $(document).unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll');
});

 
function stopWheel(e){
    if(!e){ /* IE7, IE8, Chrome, Safari */ 
        e = window.event; 
    }
    if(e.preventDefault) { /* Chrome, Safari, Firefox */ 
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just using this css to your div

```
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you, I want disable only mouse wheel when is over in text aera and not when it' is over on scroll ba

Comment: As mainly indicated in my title